# Make PhpStorm indent proper amount of indent after bracket+comma

Tags: tabs, phpstorm, newline, indentation, space

Currently, when I have the following (`|` is where the cursor is at):

```
  '/about': {
    component: {
        template: '#about-template'
    }
  },|
```

and I press enter, the cursor goes here

```
  '/about': {
    component: {
        template: '#about-template'
    }
  },
    |
```

but I want the cursor to go here:

```
  '/about': {
    component: {
        template: '#about-template'
    }
  },
  |
```

Here is an image for reference:

[image: too much indent on PhpStorm enter new line]

with the arrow pointing to where I want the new line's indent to start.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: and when I press back, it doesn't remove one indent, but instead goes back up to the previous line, which forces sort of a staircase effect when I continue programming this way.

Comment: and this is inside a script tag writing js for vue.js in case that helps

Comment: the indent after enter is perfectly fine if there is only a ending bracket, the problem starts when I have a comma after the ending bracket, which I need for Vue.js programming.

Answer (score 0):

I made the indents for javascript to 2 spaces and it fixed the problem. It was my settings error. The indent was previously set to 4 spaces, which for me was causing the problem.